# How do I halve the BPM of a project without messing up the timing on everything?

Tags: ableton-live, ableton

I'm brand new to producing and have been messing around with a song in 160 BPM, but it's unfortunately double-timed to what I actually want the song to be. How do I change my song to 80PBM without messing up every track?

Comment: Hi Sheridan and welcome! Why does it matter what the BPM is labelled as in the software? Is there a specific reason you want it correct? I've done double-time projects myself (in other DAWs), and I just halve the synced effect timing.

Comment: What software are you using? Some DAWs have the ability to halve or double all selected note values

Comment: @n00dles I've heard that using double-time BPM isn't best practice, but maybe I'm wrong about that?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm using ableton